# How to get actual product images out of ExactOnline using the API and Picqer-Exact-Php-Client

Tags: php, exact-online, picqer-exact-php-client

I am using the picqer exact client to retrieve product data from exactonline. I would like to get the actual image out of eol. Following code indeed retrieves all 1700+ active products in eol:

```
   $conn = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\BulkItem($connection);
   $today = date('Y-m-d');
   $items = $conn->filter("StartDate le datetime'{$today}T23:59:59' and (EndDate ge datetime'{$today}T00:00:00' or EndDate eq null)", '', 'ID,Barcode, Code, Description, ExtraDescription, ItemGroupCode, ItemGroupDescription, PictureName, PictureUrl, SalesVatCode, SalesVatCodeDescription, StandardSalesPrice, Stock', ['$top' => 10000]);
```

I get PictureUrl but the url is only usable when a user is logged in to eol. It cannot be used in the API.

Any ideas how to get the actual image using the API?

> *Note: StartDate and Endate in the filter is my hack to get only 'active' products. There may be a more elegant filter to achieve the same.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eol docs for another endpoint mention to add "&Download=1" for fetching the actual attachment instead of an url (https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=DocumentsDocumentAttachments). Searching the picqer code for "Download=1" led to the solution. Too bad the picqer library is rather sparsely documented - could have saved me hours.

This gets the actual product picture out of exactonline for active products:

```
$conn = new \Picqer\Financials\Exact\BulkItem($connection);
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$items = $conn->filter("StartDate le datetime'{$today}T23:59:59' and (EndDate ge datetime'{$today}T00:00:00' or EndDate eq null)", '', 'ID,Barcode, Code, Description, ExtraDescription, ItemGroupCode, ItemGroupDescription, PictureName, PictureUrl, SalesVatCode, SalesVatCodeDescription, StandardSalesPrice, Stock', ['$top' => 10000]);
foreach ($items as $item){
   $picture = $item->download();
   // do something with $picture, for instance imagecreatefromstring($picture)
};
```

Comment: `$item->download()` uses `$item->PictureUrl` to determine where to fetch the image. As of a few days ago, ExactOnline includes the OptimizeForWeb parameter in the url. This results in the loss of transparency in downloaded images. If that is not wanted, do `$item->PictureUrl = str_replace('&OptimizeForWeb=1','', $item->PictureUrl);` before calling `$item->download();`

Answer (score 0):

See https://forums.invantive.com/t/retrieve-blob-of-image-url-on-exact-online/39/2. Just retrieve the BLOB over the secure channel.

Comment: Thanks, Guido. But your answer seems to require an invantive library or something like that (with which I am not familiar). I would like to use just the picqer library, nothing else.

Comment: Please find the logic described, not the tech used to address it.

Comment: I think I go with the well-hidden `download()` method provided by the picqer library, but thanks again for taking the time.